# Mapping a servlet in my JSP

Tags: java, servlets, ejb-3.0

I have Java EE application which has a WAR file and an EJB file. The WAR file contains my jsps/html and my EJB contains my servlets/beans and EJB. I try to call my servlet in one of my jsp pages, but it cant find it. The file im looking for is Authenticate. Its located in my EJB file so i figure the path for it would be

```
action="../../EJBShoppingCart-ejb/build/classes/Servlet/Authenticate
```

I played around with URL, modifying it by taking taking away build or classes and a bunch of other ways.... my servlet has the  @WebServlet(name = "Authenticate",
 urlPatterns = {"/Authenticate"}) annotation.

I know I can transfer all of my files from my EJB file to my WAR file and I think that would solve the problem. But is there a way to map it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> urlPatterns = {"/Authenticate"}
> ```

So, it's mapped on an URL pattern of `/Authenticate`. Assuming that your server runs on localhost:8080 and the webapp context name is `myapp` and the `/WEB-INF/web.xml` is conform Servlet 3.0 spec, then you can access it by http://localhost:8080/myapp/Authenticate

---

*I'm only not entirely sure whether an `@WebServlet` class inside an EJB would ever be located and loaded by the servletcontainer. Servlets usually go in WAR and end up in `/WEB-INF/classes`. Inside a JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` is definitely possible, it has only to contain a Servlet 3.0 compatible `/META-INF/web.xml`*

Comment: I tried that, it doesnt work. http://localhost:47092/EJBShoppingCart/Authenticate   and   http://localhost:47092/EJBShoppingCart-ejb/Authenticate

Comment: Then put it in WAR, there where it technically belongs. The business tier shouldn't be aware about any classes of the web tier.